# Fix error Gravatar alt

Tags: php

```
add_filter( 'get_avatar' , 'alt_name_avatar');
function alt_name_avatar( $avatar ) {
    $alt = get_comment_author();
    $avatar = str_replace('alt=\'\'','alt=\'Avatar for '.$alt.'\' title=\'Avatar for '.$alt.'\'',$avatar);
    return $avatar;
}
```

This code works but throws an error.

```
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'user_id' of non-object in .../wp-includes/comment-template.php on line 28
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'comment_ID' of non-object in .../wp-includes/comment-template.php on line 48
```

How to fix.

**P.S.**
i use on all pages recent comments with Gravatar in the sidebar

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't check anywhere that you're viewing a comment when you use `get_comment_author();`. The `get_avatar()` function is used in [a lot of places in WordPress](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_avatar/#used-by); your code seems to assume it's *only* in use on comments.

Try this (the code is untested, but should work, I think):

```
add_filter( 'get_avatar' , 'alt_name_avatar');
function alt_name_avatar( $avatar ) {
    if ( null === get_comment() ) {
        // This isn't a comment.
        return $avatar;
    }
    $alt = get_comment_author();
    $avatar = str_replace('alt=\'\'','alt=\'Avatar for '.$alt.'\' title=\'Avatar for '.$alt.'\'',$avatar);
    return $avatar;
}
```

There doesn't seem to be a simple `is_comment()` check to see if we're viewing a comment, so I've chosen to test [`get_comment()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comment/), which will return `null` if we're not in a comment.

Comment: Thank you! Now there are no mistakes :-)